# Second Fundamental Theorem for $SO(m,n)$

Tags: invariant-theory

I want to ask you if you know any reference where the second fundamental theorem for $SO(n)$ is stated and proved. I have been looking for it but my quest has been useless. By classical invariant theory, we know that the ring of invariants for $SO(m,n)$ is generated by the scalar products and the determinants, but I want to know what are the relations between them. Is this an open problem? I couldn't find any hints on the internet.

Thank you.

Comment: My first google hit is [this paper](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwirotHytZ3sAhVrA2MBHaydBWsQFjAAegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fannals.math.princeton.edu%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fannals-v176-n3-p12-p.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1F-wzQM0PfHN-TfYu-hyol). It looks promising. Perhaps you can search a bit more.

Comment: The invariant theory for SO(n) is slightly more complicated than the one for O(n).